# Error with routing and headers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, routes, http-headers

I'm with the following problem:

I'm trying to create a route with a default format type as JSON:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :pessoas_fisicas, defaults: { format: 'json' }
    end
  end
end
```

When I access the URL http://api.sistema-controle-contas.com:3000/v1/pessoas_fisicas, it shows the expected result, a JSON output.

The controller that I'm using for this code is:

```
 def index
    @pessoas_fisicas = PessoaFisica.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @pessoas_fisicas, status: 200 }
      format.xml { render xml: @pessoas_fisicas, status: 200 }
    end
 end
```

But It always return a JSON file, even if I send a header asking for a XML like this:

```
$ curl -IH 'Accept: application/xml' 'http://api.sistema-controle-contas.com:3000/v1/pessoas_fisicas'
```

It returns:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

If I took off the 'defaults: { format: 'json' }' from the route, the curl request return the XML expected. However, the application stops to work as it does not know the format that is needed to show.

And on the Browser I got:

```
"status": 406,
"error": "Not Acceptable",
"exception": "#<ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat>"
```

Could someone help with this, please?

Comment: Have you tried to add `Content-Type: application/xml` headers to the curl request?

Comment: you've got `defaults: { format: 'json' }` on your routes.rb, try removing it.

Comment: @Зелёный, I tried to add this header, but it did not work either.

Comment: @sa77, if I revome the defult I got "status": 406,
"error": "Not Acceptable",
"exception": "#<ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat>", in the application (on the browser).